# Reference DOM with $(this) after plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm no jquery plugin expert. I'm using a plugin from http://lab.narf.pl/jquery-typing/ that basically allows me to call a function n seconds after a keypress. However, when I call the function I want to pass the DOM at hand to it:

```
$('.liveSave').typing({
    start: function () {
        $('#savingInfo').html('Saving...');
    },
    stop: function () {
        saveInfo($(this));
    },
    delay: 1000
});
```

However, `$(this)` doesn't seem to be passing the element I called "typing" on. I'm guessing it's passing the typing instance (or something, I'm not sure how to find out what the object is).

Does this mean there's something missing from the plugin? If so, could you help me know what to include and where? (the plugin isn't huge, but you can see the source code at the link I attached to this question)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: its clearly mentioned in its docs:: http://lab.narf.pl/jquery-typing/ on how to use it, did you even see its example before using it..?

Comment: First thing I'd have tried, barring documentation: `stop: function () { console.log(arguments) },`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right there on [front page](http://lab.narf.pl/jquery-typing/) shows it passed in as the second argument

```
start: function (event, $elem) {
                        ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry, it was probably obvious I'm kind of new at this I guess I didn't understand the documentation. Thanks for being helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](http://lab.narf.pl/jquery-typing/) the `start` and `stop` callbacks provide `$elem` as the second parameter, which you can use

```
$('.liveSave').typing({
    start: function (event, $elem) {
        $('#savingInfo').html('Saving...');
    },
    stop: function (event, $elem) {
        saveInfo( $elem);
    },
    delay: 1000
});
```